# How many solutions are there for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 49$?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

How many solutions are there for this equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 49\,,$$ where $x_i,\;i= 1,2,3,4$ is a non negative integer such that:$$ 1\le x_1\le 8,\;3\le x_2\le 9,\;10\le x_3\le 20,\ 0\le x_4\,?$$

Comment: This is a composition problem. One way to solve this is to first adjust the constraints to only have upper bounds and then use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Since none of the sums exceeds the total, you could just say that you have 8 choices for $x_1$, 7 choices for $x_2$, 10 choices for $x_3$, and for  a unique combination of these, $x_4$ is fixed

Comment: Please typeset your question using *MathJax*.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan You mean $11$ choices for $x_3$, because the endpoints of the range $[10,20]$ are both included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left\{ \matrix{
  1 \le x_{\,1}  \le 8 \hfill \cr 
  3 \le x_{\,2}  \le 9 \hfill \cr 
  10 \le x_{\,3}  \le 20 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le x_{\,4} \left( { \le 49} \right) \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  = 49 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  x_{\,1}  = y_{\,1}  + 1\; \to \;0 \le y_{\,1}  \le 7 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,2}  = y_{\,2}  + 3\; \to 0 \le y_{\,2}  \le 6 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,3}  = y_{\,3}  + 10\; \to 0 \le y_{\,3}  \le 10 \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,4}  = y_{\,4} \; \to 0 \le y_{\,4} \left( { \le 49} \right) \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + y_{\,3}  + y_{\,4}  = 49 - 14 = 35 \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le y_{\,1}  \le 7 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y_{\,2}  \le 6 \hfill \cr 
  0 \le y_{\,3}  \le 10 \hfill \cr 
  y_{\,1}  + y_{\,2}  + y_{\,3}  \le 35 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$

Now, since the upper limits sum to $23 < 35$, then all the points inside
the parallepiped $[0,7] \times [0,6] \times [0,10]$ respect the last 
inequality, thus
$$
N = 8 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 = 616
$$

Comment: @BarryCipra: yes, of course it is $11$, sorry for the banal lapse and thanks for signalling

Answer (score 0):

Well, just a quick search with Mathematica gives:

```
In[1]:=Length[Solve[{x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 49, 
   1 <= x1 <= 8 && 3 <= x2 <= 9 && 10 <= x3 <= 20 && 0 <= x4}, {x1, 
   x2, x3, x4}, Integers]]

Out[1]=616
```

So, there are $616$ solutions.

---

And the solutions are:

```
In[2]:=Solve[{x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 49, 
  1 <= x1 <= 8 && 3 <= x2 <= 9 && 10 <= x3 <= 20 && 0 <= x4}, {x1, x2,
   x3, x4}, Integers]

Out[2]={{x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 35}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 34}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 34}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 1, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 1, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 34}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 2, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 2, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 33}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 3, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 3, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 32}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 4, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 4, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 31}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 5, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 30}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 6, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 6, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 29}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 7, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 7, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 13}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 28}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 3, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 3, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 27}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 4, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 4, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 26}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 5, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 5, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 25}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 6, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 6, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 10, 
  x4 -> 24}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 13, 
  x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 16, 
  x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 7, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 19, 
  x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 7, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 23}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 11, 
  x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 12, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 14, 
  x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 15, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 17, 
  x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 18, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 8, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 8, x3 -> 20, 
  x4 -> 13}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 10, x4 -> 22}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 11, x4 -> 21}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 12, 
  x4 -> 20}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 13, x4 -> 19}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 14, x4 -> 18}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 15, 
  x4 -> 17}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 16, x4 -> 16}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 17, x4 -> 15}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 18, 
  x4 -> 14}, {x1 -> 8, x2 -> 9, x3 -> 19, x4 -> 13}, {x1 -> 8, 
  x2 -> 9, x3 -> 20, x4 -> 12}}
```

Comment: Computers are great for many problems, but not for this one. As Dhanvi Sreenivasan commented under the question, the upper bounds $8,9,20$ add up to less than 49, and so the solutions can be described succinctly as "any of the 8 allowed values for $x_1$, any of the 7 allowed values for $x_2$, any of the 11 allowed values for $x_3$, and the unique value for $x_4$ that brings the sum up to 49.  In particular, the number of solutions is $8\times7\times11=616$.